# How to update style after ajax call in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, ajax, css-selectors

I have dynamicaly added input fields like this one:

```
<input id="person__1_badge_number" class="number" type="text" size="12" name="person[][1][badge][number]"/>
```

And when I add this field I call fallowing function:

```
function please_rebind() {
  $('.number').bind("change", function() {
    $.post('/registration/sell/check_badge_number', { number: $(this).val() },
    function(data) {
      $(this).addClass('make_it_red');
      alert(data);
    }, "html");
 });
}
```

And it didn't add 'make_it_red' class to my input field (I also tried html('foo') and other stuff and it also doesn't work). I think it is becouse I run $(this) inside other function, but I don't know what to do with it.
$(this).val() works and I also get correct response (alert(data)). Can anybody help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think what is happening is that after the callback, the reference to $(this) is lost. Try it this way:

```
function please_rebind() {
  $('.number').bind("change", function() {
    var that = $(this);
    $.post('/registration/sell/check_badge_number', { number: $(this).val() },
    function(data) {
      that.addClass('make_it_red');          
    }, "html");
 });
}
```

Comment: Just wanted to add that "this" within the callback for $.post refers to the options for the given ajax request.

Comment: this is one of the recurring thorns in JS, the volatility of 'this'.  just remember to use this trick whenever you define a callback.  Of course, this makes the function a full closure, which is considered 'bad practice' performance-wise by IE developers.  they prefer to keep JScript non-performant on these cases.

Answer (score 2):

You can reference the element by id:

```
$('#person__1_badge_number').addClass('make_it_red');
```

Also, it depends on how you've dynamically inserted the element, if you just appended it as a string to some div, for example, it may not be bound to the DOM.

EDIT: you can get the element ID from within the binding, and build the selector within the callback:

```
 function please_rebind() {
  $('.number').bind("change", function() {
    var elementId = this.id;
    $.post('/registration/sell/check_badge_number', { number: $(this).val() },
    function(data) {
      $('#' + elementId).addClass('make_it_red');
      alert(data);
    }, "html");
 });
}
```